# Adding Buttons to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I have 208 Buttons and I want to assign numbers to them by using an array. These buttons have different images on top of them and I want them to appear on the screen when I put the according number, which represents the Button on the screen. The 2D Array can be ignored. I know that I have to get rid of this code and write code for the array in the place of this one, but I can't figure what I have to do.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.lang.Object;

public class CBallMaze extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    private JButton Jbuttonoption1;
    private JButton Jbuttonoption2;
    private JButton Jbuttonoption3;
    private JButton Jbuttonblank1;
    private JButton Jbuttonup;
    private JButton Jbuttonblank2;
    private JButton Jbuttonleft;
    private JButton Jbuttonblank3;
    private JButton Jbuttonright;
    private JButton Jbuttonblank4;
    private JButton Jbuttondown;
    private JButton Jbuttonblank5;
    private JButton Jbuttonexit;
    private JButton Jbuttonact;
    private Icon iconAct;
    private JButton Jbuttonrun;
    private Icon iconRun;
    private JButton Jbuttonreset;
    private Icon iconReset;
    private Icon iconCompassnorth;
    private Icon iconCompasseast;
    private Icon iconCompasssouth;
    private Icon iconCompasswest;
    private JButton JButtoncompass;
    private JPanel JPanelSouth;
    private JPanel JPanelSouthButtons;
    private JPanel JPanelSouthSlider;
    private JPanel JPaneleast;
    private JPanel JPaneleastoptionbutton;
    private JPanel JPaneleastmiddle;
    private JPanel JPaneleastcompass;
    private JPanel JPaneleasttextfields; 
    private JTextField JTextField1;
    private JLabel JLabelTextField1;
    private JTextField JTextField2;
    private JLabel JLabelTextField2;
    private JTextField JTextField3;
    private JLabel JLabelTextField3;
    private JPanel JPanelnorth;
    private JButton[] JGridButton = new JButton[208];
    private JPanel JPanelnorthwest;
    private JMenuBar JMenuBar1;
    private JMenu scenarioMenu;
    private JMenu editMenu;
    private JMenu controlsMenu;
    private JMenu helpMenu;
    private JMenuItem exitItem;
    private JMenuItem fontItem;
    private JMenuItem foreColor;
    private JMenuItem backColor;
    private JMenuItem helpItem;
    private JMenuItem aboutItem;
    private JSlider JSlider1;
    private JTextField JSliderTextfield;
   /* private ImageIcon[] sandimage = new ImageIcon[1];
    private ImageIcon[] whiteimage = new ImageIcon[2];
    private ImageIcon[] goldenball = new ImageIcon[4];
    private ImageIcon[] sandstone = new ImageIcon[3];*/
    private Icon sandimage;
    private Icon whiteimage;
    private Icon goldenball;
    private Icon sandstone;
    private Icon greenfoot;

    private int nPosition = 15;

   /* int [][] map1 = {  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4},
                      {2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                      {2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                      {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                      {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                      {2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2},
                      {2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2},
                      {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                      {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                      {2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
                      {3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} };*/

    int [] map1 = {  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4,
                     2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                     2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        CBallMaze frame = new CBallMaze();
        frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("res/greenfoot.jpg"));
        frame.setTitle("CBallMaze");
        frame.setSize(775, 650);
        frame.createGUI();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        JMenuBar menuBar1 = new JMenuBar();

        try
        {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Couldn't use the system "+"look and feel: "+e);
        }

        JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("Scenario");
        fileMenu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        menuBar1.add(fileMenu);

        JMenu fileMenu0 = new JMenu("Edit");
        fileMenu0.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        menuBar1.add(fileMenu0);

        JMenu fileMenu1 = new JMenu("Controls");
        fileMenu1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        menuBar1.add(fileMenu1);

        JMenu fileMenu2 = new JMenu("Help");
        fileMenu2.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
        menuBar1.add(fileMenu2);

        frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar1);
        frame.setSize(775,650);
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }


    private void createGUI()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container window = getContentPane();
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout() );
        centreWindow();

        JPanelnorth = new JPanel();
        JPanelnorth.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(630, 600));
        JPanelnorth.setBackground(Color.white);
        JPanelnorth.setLayout(new GridLayout(13,16));
        window.add(JPanelnorth,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        try 
        {
            iconAct = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/Act.jpg")));
            iconRun = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/Run.jpg")));
            iconReset = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/Reset.jpg")));
            iconCompassnorth = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/north.jpg")));
            iconCompasseast = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/east.jpg")));
            iconCompasssouth = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/south.jpg")));
            iconCompasswest = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/west.jpg")));
            sandimage = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/sand.jpg")));
            whiteimage = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/white32x32.jpg")));
            goldenball = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/sand60x60.png")));
            sandstone = new ImageIcon(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(CBallMaze.class.getResource("images/sandstone.jpg")));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Baby Icon ImageIcon "+e);
        } 


        for( int nCount= 0; nCount < 208; nCount++ )
        {
            JGridButton[nCount] = new JButton(""); 
            JPanelnorth.add(JGridButton[nCount]);
            JGridButton[nCount].setBorderPainted(false);
            if((nCount >= 0 && nCount<=15) 
                    || (nCount >= 48 && nCount <= 63)
                    || (nCount >= 96 && nCount <= 111)
                    || (nCount >= 144 && nCount <= 159)
                    || (nCount >= 193 && nCount <= 208)
                    || (nCount == 17) || (nCount == 33)
                    || (nCount == 21) || (nCount == 37)
                    || (nCount == 25) || (nCount == 41)
                    || (nCount == 66) || (nCount == 82)
                    || (nCount == 70) || (nCount == 86)
                    || (nCount == 75) || (nCount == 91)
                    || (nCount == 113) || (nCount == 129)
                    || (nCount == 117) || (nCount == 133)
                    || (nCount == 124) || (nCount == 140)
                    || (nCount == 162) || (nCount == 178)
                    || (nCount == 166) || (nCount == 182)

                    )
            {
                JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(sandimage);
            }
            else 
            {
                JGridButton[nCount].setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            if(nCount == 192)
            {
                JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(sandstone);
            }
            if(nCount == 15)
            {
                JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(goldenball);
            }

        }


        JPaneleast = new JPanel();
        JPaneleast.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(145, 600));
        JPaneleast.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        window.add(JPaneleast,BorderLayout.EAST);

        JPanelSouth = new JPanel();
        JPanelSouth.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(705, 50));
        JPanelSouth.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        window.add(JPanelSouth,BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        JPaneleasttextfields = new JPanel();
        JPaneleasttextfields.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(145,100));
        JPaneleasttextfields.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        JPaneleasttextfields.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));
        JPaneleast.add(JPaneleasttextfields);

        JLabelTextField1 = new JLabel("Option:");
        JLabelTextField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65,33));
        JPaneleasttextfields.add(JLabelTextField1);

        JTextField1 = new JTextField();
        JTextField1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80 ,33));
        JPaneleasttextfields.add(JTextField1);

        JLabelTextField2 = new JLabel("Square:");
        JLabelTextField2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65,33));
        JPaneleasttextfields.add(JLabelTextField2);

        JTextField2 = new JTextField();
        JTextField2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80 ,33));
        JPaneleasttextfields.add(JTextField2);

        JLabelTextField3 = new JLabel("Direction:");
        JLabelTextField3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(65,33));
        JPaneleasttextfields.add(JLabelTextField3);

        JTextField3 = new JTextField();
        JTextField3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80 ,33));
        JPaneleasttextfields.add(JTextField3);

        JPaneleastmiddle = new JPanel();
        JPaneleastmiddle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 100));
        JPaneleastmiddle.setBackground(Color.gray);
        JPaneleastmiddle.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3) );
        window.add(JPaneleastmiddle,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPaneleast.add(JPaneleastmiddle); 

        Jbuttonblank1 = new JButton("");
        JPaneleastmiddle.add(Jbuttonblank1);
        Jbuttonblank1.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonblank1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
        Jbuttonblank1.setEnabled(false);

        Jbuttonup = new JButton("^");
        JPaneleastmiddle.add(Jbuttonup);
        Jbuttonup.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonup.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));

        Jbuttonblank2 = new JButton("");
        JPaneleastmiddle.add(Jbuttonblank2);
        Jbuttonblank2.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonblank2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
        Jbuttonblank2.setEnabled(false);

        Jbuttonleft = new JButton("<");
        JPaneleastmiddle.add(Jbuttonleft);
        Jbuttonleft.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonleft.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));

        Jbuttonblank3 = new JButton("");
        JPaneleastmiddle.add(Jbuttonblank3);
        Jbuttonblank3.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonblank3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
        Jbuttonblank3.setEnabled(false);

        Jbuttonright = new JButton(">");
        JPaneleastmiddle.add(Jbuttonright);
        Jbuttonright.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonright.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));

        Jbuttonblank4 = new JButton("");
        JPaneleastmiddle.add(Jbuttonblank4);
        Jbuttonblank4.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonblank4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
        Jbuttonblank4.setEnabled(false);

        Jbuttondown = new JButton("v");
        JPaneleastmiddle.add(Jbuttondown);
        Jbuttondown.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttondown.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));

        Jbuttonblank5 = new JButton("");
        JPaneleastmiddle.add(Jbuttonblank5);
        Jbuttonblank5.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonblank5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));
        Jbuttonblank5.setEnabled(false);

        JPaneleastoptionbutton = new JPanel();
        JPaneleastoptionbutton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(160, 60));
        JPaneleastoptionbutton.setBackground(Color.gray);
        JPaneleastoptionbutton.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2) );
        JPaneleast.add(JPaneleastoptionbutton);

        Jbuttonoption1 = new JButton("Option1");
        JPaneleastoptionbutton.add(Jbuttonoption1);
        Jbuttonoption1.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonoption1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));

        Jbuttonoption2 = new JButton("Option2");
        JPaneleastoptionbutton.add(Jbuttonoption2);
        Jbuttonoption2.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonoption2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));

        Jbuttonoption3 = new JButton("Option3");
        JPaneleastoptionbutton.add(Jbuttonoption3);
        Jbuttonoption3.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonoption3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));

        Jbuttonexit = new JButton("Exit");
        JPaneleastoptionbutton.add(Jbuttonexit);
        Jbuttonexit.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonexit.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 30));

        JPaneleastcompass = new JPanel();
        JPaneleastcompass.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        JPaneleastcompass.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        JPaneleast.add(JPaneleastcompass);


        JPanelSouthButtons = new JPanel();
        JPanelSouthButtons.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(270, 30));
        JPanelSouthButtons.setBackground(Color.gray);
        JPanelSouthButtons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3) );
        JPanelSouth.add(JPanelSouthButtons);

        Jbuttonact = new JButton("Act");
        JPanelSouthButtons.add(Jbuttonact);
        Jbuttonact.setIcon(iconAct);
        Jbuttonact.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonact.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 30));

        Jbuttonrun = new JButton("Run");
        JPanelSouthButtons.add(Jbuttonrun);
        Jbuttonrun.setIcon(iconRun);
        Jbuttonrun.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonrun.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 30));


        Jbuttonreset = new JButton("Reset");
        JPanelSouthButtons.add(Jbuttonreset);
        Jbuttonreset.setIcon(iconReset);
        Jbuttonreset.addActionListener(this);
        Jbuttonreset.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 30));


        JPanelSouthSlider = new JPanel();
        JPanelSouthSlider.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        JPanelSouthSlider.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        JPanelSouthSlider.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));
        JPanelSouth.add(JPanelSouthSlider);

        JSlider1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL,200,2000,1000);
        JSlider1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 30));
        JPanelSouthSlider.add(JSlider1);

        JButtoncompass = new JButton();
        JPaneleastcompass.add(JButtoncompass);
        JButtoncompass.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        JButtoncompass.setIcon(iconCompassnorth);


    }

    public void centreWindow()
    {    
      Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      Dimension frameSize = getSize();
      if (frameSize.height > screenSize.height)
      {
        frameSize.height = screenSize.height;
      }
      if (frameSize.width > screenSize.width)
      {
        frameSize.width = screenSize.width;
      }
      setLocation((screenSize.width - frameSize.width) / 2, 
                  (screenSize.height - frameSize.height) / 2);
     }

    public void gameEnd()
    {
        if(nPosition == 193)
        {   

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    public void Option1()
    {
        JTextField1.setText("Option1");
    }

    public void Option2()
    {
        JTextField1.setText("Option2");
    }

    public void Option3()
    {
        JTextField1.setText("Option3");
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Object source = event.getSource();
        gameEnd();

        if(source == Jbuttonoption1)
        {
            Option1();
        }

        if(source == Jbuttonoption2)
        {
            Option2();
        }

        if(source == Jbuttonoption3)
        {
            Option3();
        }

        if(source == Jbuttonup)
        {
            JButtoncompass.setIcon(iconCompassnorth);
            JTextField3.setText("N");
            JGridButton[nPosition -16].setIcon(goldenball);
            JGridButton[nPosition].setIcon(sandimage);
            //JTextField2.set
            nPosition = nPosition -16;
        }

        if(source == Jbuttonright)
        {
            JButtoncompass.setIcon(iconCompasseast);
            JTextField3.setText("E");
            JGridButton[nPosition +1].setIcon(goldenball);
            JGridButton[nPosition].setIcon(sandimage);
            nPosition = nPosition +1;
        }

        if(source == Jbuttondown)
        {
            JButtoncompass.setIcon(iconCompasssouth);
            JTextField3.setText("S");
            JGridButton[nPosition +16].setIcon(goldenball);
            JGridButton[nPosition].setIcon(sandimage);
            nPosition = nPosition +16;
        }

        if(source == Jbuttonleft)
        {
            if(nPosition <= 0)
            {

            }
            else{
            JButtoncompass.setIcon(iconCompasswest);
            JTextField3.setText("W");
            JGridButton[nPosition -1].setIcon(goldenball);
            JGridButton[nPosition].setIcon(sandimage);
            nPosition = nPosition -1;}

        }

        if(source == Jbuttonoption1)
        {

        }

        if(source == Jbuttonoption2)
        {

        }

        if(source == Jbuttonoption3)
        {

        }

        if(source == Jbuttonexit)
        {
            System.exit(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }
    }
}





for( int nCount= 0; nCount < 208; nCount++ )
        {
            JGridButton[nCount] = new JButton(""); 
            JPanelnorth.add(JGridButton[nCount]);
            JGridButton[nCount].setBorderPainted(false);
            if((nCount >= 0 && nCount<=15) 
                    || (nCount >= 48 && nCount <= 63)
                    || (nCount >= 96 && nCount <= 111)
                    || (nCount >= 144 && nCount <= 159)
                    || (nCount >= 193 && nCount <= 208)
                    || (nCount == 17) || (nCount == 33)
                    || (nCount == 21) || (nCount == 37)
                    || (nCount == 25) || (nCount == 41)
                    || (nCount == 66) || (nCount == 82)
                    || (nCount == 70) || (nCount == 86)
                    || (nCount == 75) || (nCount == 91)
                    || (nCount == 113) || (nCount == 129)
                    || (nCount == 117) || (nCount == 133)
                    || (nCount == 124) || (nCount == 140)
                    || (nCount == 162) || (nCount == 178)
                    || (nCount == 166) || (nCount == 182)

                    )
            {
                JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(sandimage);
            }
            else 
            {
                JGridButton[nCount].setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            if(nCount == 192)
            {
                JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(sandstone);
            }
            if(nCount == 15)
            {
                JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(goldenball);
            }

        }
```

I have to delete this code, I think and replace it with some other code for the array.

```
if((nCount >= 0 && nCount<=15) 
                        || (nCount >= 48 && nCount <= 63)
                        || (nCount >= 96 && nCount <= 111)
                        || (nCount >= 144 && nCount <= 159)
                        || (nCount >= 193 && nCount <= 208)
                        || (nCount == 17) || (nCount == 33)
                        || (nCount == 21) || (nCount == 37)
                        || (nCount == 25) || (nCount == 41)
                        || (nCount == 66) || (nCount == 82)
                        || (nCount == 70) || (nCount == 86)
                        || (nCount == 75) || (nCount == 91)
                        || (nCount == 113) || (nCount == 129)
                        || (nCount == 117) || (nCount == 133)
                        || (nCount == 124) || (nCount == 140)
                        || (nCount == 162) || (nCount == 178)
                        || (nCount == 166) || (nCount == 182)

                        )
```

Comment: Please clarify your question -- what *exactly* are you trying to do? *Where* are you stuck?

Comment: Why not use **one** button and change its caption / action dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to create a grid of Images held by buttons. If so, then simply create your 2-dimensional array of JButton, don't give the buttons names, and create your JButtons in a for loop, adding them to the array and to the GridLayout-using JPanel at the same time. You can then use the same grid to assign ImageIcons for each button.

Your map should be held by a text file, not hard-coded in your code, and you can then read the map into its own 2D array, and use this as the basis for creating and iterating through your button grid.

e.g.,

```
  // first read in the text file and fill the map 2D int array

  for (int row = 0; row < btnGrid.length; row++) {
     for (int col = 0; col < btnGrid[row].length; col++) {
        int value = map[row][col]; // holds value for icons array
        Icon icon = icons[value]; // an array of ImageIcons
        btnGrid[row][col] = new JButton(icon);
        btnGrid[row][col].addActionListener(someListener);
        btnPanel.add(btnGrid[row][col]);
     }
  }
```

In the JButton's Action or ActionListener (here noted as `someListener`), you'd change the state of the button, perhaps its icon, on button press, depending on your need.